React native tts (text to speech) with cursor follow the speech in text input react native
I have a small app which is used to learn pronunciation , I have a rest api which i have text coming from it into the app , which is placed in text input , i am using react native tts to Speek out the text , now i need the cursor to follow the words , and when i select some text from that point it needs to speak.
When i have cursor following then text selection won't work and vice versa.
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  ToastAndroid,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  AppState,
  ActivityIndicator,
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  TextInputSelectionChangeEventData,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Tts from 'react-native-tts';
import {SelectList} from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list';
import {SingleItem} from '../../lib/types';
import {pitch, voices} from '../../store/Store';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import {appColors} from '../../appColors/AppColors';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

const ICON_SIZE = 100;

const TextToVoice = ({route}: any) => {
  const {item} = route.params as {item: SingleItem};
  const [selectedVoice, setSelectedVoice] = useState('');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [_, setPitchRate] = useState<number>(1);
  const [first, setFirst] = useState(true);
  const [selectedVoiceType, setSelectedVoiceType] = useState<string>('Male');
  const animationRef = useRef<LottieView>(null);
  const [lastPosition, setLastPosition] = useState({
    start: 0,
    end: 0,
  });
  const [isImageLoading, setIsImageLoading] = useState(true);
  const textInputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  const play = async () => {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      Tts.speak(item.text);
      setIsPlaying(true);
    }
  };

  const stop = async () => {
    animationRef?.current?.play(0, 0);
    await Tts.stop();
    setLastPosition({start: 0, end: 0});
    setIsPlaying(false);
  };

  const pause = async () => {
    const isStopped = await Tts.stop();
    console.log(isStopped, 'stopped');
    setIsPlaying(isStopped);
  };

  const handleCursorPosition = async (event: any) => {
    event.persist();
    await stop();
    const cursorPosition = event.nativeEvent.selection.start;
    const textBeforeCursor = item.text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
    const lastSpacePosition = textBeforeCursor.lastIndexOf(' ');
    const slice1 = item.text.slice(lastSpacePosition + 1, cursorPosition);
    const slice2 = item.text.slice(cursorPosition);
    const text = slice1 + slice2;
    const cursorPoint = item.text.indexOf(text.trim());
    setLastPosition({start: cursorPoint, end: cursorPoint});

    // Determine voice type based on the cursor position or selected text
    const voiceIndex = cursorPosition % voices.length;
    const selectedVoice = voices[voiceIndex];
    setSelectedVoiceType(selectedVoice.value);
    Tts.speak(text);
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const handleSelectChange = async (val: string) => {
    try {
      await stop();
      const voiceChange = await Tts.setDefaultVoice(val);
      if (voiceChange === 'success') {
        setSelectedVoice(val);
        const voiceIndex = voices.findIndex(voice => voice.key === val);
        const selectedVoice = voices[voiceIndex];
        setSelectedVoiceType(selectedVoice.value);

        const sentenceToSpeak = item.text.substring(
          lastPosition.start,
          item.text.length,
        );

        if (!first) Tts.speak(sentenceToSpeak);
        setFirst(false);
      } else {
        ToastAndroid.show('Failed to change voice', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'error at handleSelectChange');
    }
  };

  const handleSelectPitchChange = async (val: number) => {
    try {
      await stop();
      const rateChange = await Tts.setDefaultRate(val);
      if (rateChange === 'success') {
        setPitchRate(val);
        const sentenceToSpeak = item.text.substring(
          lastPosition.start,
          item.text.length,
        );
        if (!first) Tts.speak(sentenceToSpeak);
        setFirst(false);
      } else {
        ToastAndroid.show('Failed to change rate of voice', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'Error At Select Change');
    }
  };

  const startEventListener = () => setIsPlaying(true);
  const finishEventListener = () => setIsPlaying(false);
  const progressEventListener = (event: any) => {
    textInputRef?.current?.setSelection(event.start, event.end);
    setLastPosition({start: event.start, end: event.end});
  }; // setting the last know position that our voice is speaking
  const errorEventListener = (event: any) => console.log(event);

  const restartSpeech = async () => {
    await stop();
    Tts.speak(item.text);
  };

  const cleanUp = async () => {
    try {
      await stop();
      Tts.removeAllListeners('tts-start');
      Tts.removeAllListeners('tts-finish');
      Tts.removeAllListeners('tts-progress');
      Tts.removeAllListeners('tts-cancel');
      Tts.removeAllListeners('tts-error');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, 'error at cleanUp');
    }
  };

  const backgroundHandler = () => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', async appState => {
      console.log(isPlaying, 'isPlaying');
      if (appState.match(/inactive|background/)) {
        // we need to stop the voice or pause it
        await stop();
      } else {
        // we have it active , we need to restart
        // if (!isPlaying) {
        //   await speakTextFromCurrentIndex();
        // }
      }
    });

    return subscription;
  };

  // attaching event listeners and AppState functions
  useEffect(() => {
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-finish', finishEventListener);
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-start', startEventListener);
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-progress', progressEventListener);
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-cancel', finishEventListener);
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-error', errorEventListener);

    const appStateChanger = backgroundHandler();

    return () => {
      cleanUp();
      appStateChanger.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Voices</Text>
            <SelectList
              setSelected={handleSelectChange}
              data={voices}
              save="key"
              boxStyles={styles.selectList}
              dropdownTextStyles={styles.dropdownText}
              placeholder="Select Voice"
              defaultOption={voices[0]}
              inputStyles={styles.selectInput}
            />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Speed</Text>
            <SelectList
              setSelected={handleSelectPitchChange}
              data={pitch}
              save="key"
              boxStyles={styles.selectList}
              dropdownTextStyles={styles.dropdownText}
              placeholder="Select Speed"
              defaultOption={pitch[2]}
              searchPlaceholder="Search Speed"
              inputStyles={styles.selectInput}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.textParent}>
          {item.image ? (
            <View style={styles.imageBackground}>
              {isImageLoading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" />}
              <Image
                source={{uri: item.image}}
                style={styles.img}
                onLoad={() => setIsImageLoading(false)}
                onLoadStart={() => setIsImageLoading(true)}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
            </View>
          ) : null}
          <View style={styles.lottieAnimation2}>
            <LottieView
              autoPlay
              ref={animationRef}
              source={
                selectedVoiceType === 'Male'
                  ? require('../../assets/lottiefiles/boyReading2.0.json')
                  : require('../../assets/lottiefiles/girlTaking.json')
              }
              loop={false}
              style={styles.lottieAnimation}
            />
            <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{selectedVoiceType}</Text>
          </View>

          <TextInput
            ref={textInputRef}
            value={item.text}
            multiline
            style={styles.text}
            onSelectionChange={handleCursorPosition}
            // autoFocus
            selectTextOnFocus
            showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.imgView}>
          <Icon.Button
            name="restart"
            size={ICON_SIZE}
            backgroundColor={appColors.primary}
            onPress={restartSpeech}
          />
          <Icon.Button
            name={isPlaying ? 'pause-circle' : 'play-circle'}
            size={ICON_SIZE}
            backgroundColor={appColors.primary}
            onPress={isPlaying ? pause : play}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TextToVoice;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  scrollView: {
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  selectContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  label: {
    color: appColors.primary,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: '600',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  selectList: {
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: appColors.primary,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  selectInput: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  dropdownText: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  textParent: {
    minHeight: 300,
    borderWidth: 2,
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: appColors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'justify',
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20,
    overflow: 'scroll',
    padding: 10,
    fontFamily: '700',
  },
  imgView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    paddingBottom: 40,
  },
  iconRestart: {
    backgroundColor: appColors.primary,
    color: '#eee',
    borderRadius: 70,
  },
  img: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 250,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  imageBackground: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: appColors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },
  lottieAnimation: {
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  },
  lottieAnimation2: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: appColors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },
});


A way to get these both working at same time
